# overlay on top of video in windows XP

Tags: c#, wpf, video, windows-xp

We have windows xp sp3 and a WPF application. Usually the cpu is around 2-3%, when we show a control on top of a video the CPU raises with 50% (relative to the control's size)!!
It does not happens on windows 7, what is the problem and what can we do?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Windows XP. Simply speaking it uses an older UI stack. I am not exactly sure how that one works (it is ANCIENT) but it may well be it has to move from using the video overlay mechanism in the graphics card (which likely is old anyway) to using projected directX surfaces. Which may be not fully supported by the ancient version. Modern Windows uses DirectX for video playback and does a lot of resizing in the graphics card (which is there anyway). This was not state of the art in Windows XP.

Best is to tell customers using Window XP that it is ENF OF LIFE FOR YEARS. Saying "it works fine" is not sane when you say "but sucks with modern software" in the same sentence.